# what resource my query is using and on which it is waiting for

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, stored-procedures, relational-database

I have a stored procedure which take the date range as an input and work on some CTE tables to produce the final result. the current problem is that the stored procedure is running for the last 3 days and there is nothing i can see on the sp_who2 procedure i.e blkby or anything. raughly i can say that the sp is working on 7000000 rows (i know this is bad but this is something old code).

now my question is 
1) what should i check (what resource it is using and for what it is waiting)
2) how can i identify the cause of this problem

please provide some starting point or link

Thanks
Atul

Comment: First of all it would be helpful if you could post all or part of your SP code.  At an off guess your SP is either done but not returning, or stuck in the middle.  If you aren't seeing it in sp_who2 I doubt it's doing anything active.

Answer (score 0):

Install [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com) by Adam Machanic.

Then you can execute the stored proc to see what type of activity is going on. You can go [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2011/04/06/who-is-active-options-a-month-of-monitoring-part-6-of-30.aspx), to see the list of params that you can pass it. I suggest using the filters to weed out just the database/username you want.

You can use this to get query plans, transaction info, and a whole bunch more. It isn't just about finding a blocked spid.